# How to block sharing?

Tags: permissions, office-2016

This question has been asked before, but the answers I've seen involve somehow changing the web page to hide the functionality. However, Office 2016 now has the "share" functionality [built-in](https://blogs.office.com/2015/10/05/share-with-the-click-of-a-button-in-office-2016/). So, how do we block sharing on a given site in a way that works in both the browser and the office client?